# Current request is not a multipart request in Angular

Tags: javascript, java, html, angular8, multipartform-data

I have an issue in angular. I can't upload an excel file through my angular but it is working on my backend through POSTMAN. In angular it shows that "Current request is not a multipart request". Anybody who know please tell me a solution.

This is my frontend code( Ts code)

```
selectFile(event){
    this.file=event.target.files[0];
    console.log(this.file);
  }
  uploadExcel() {
    console.log("inside");
    let formData = new FormData();
    // data.append('file', input.files[0])
    formData.append('file',this.file[0]);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8802/va2-interbanking-service/interbanking/upload',formData).subscribe(
      (Response)=>{});
}
```

I want a solution for this error